# Message written in StatusBar is changed after hovering over a button in QMenuBar but is not reverted when the mouse leaves the button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently designing an application (as a practice to learn PyQt5 better since I am new to Qt) where I have a StatusBar which I display a message on. Recently, I decided to implement a save function by using QAction object in QMenuBar and I set its status tip.

My problem with this is that it shows the tip when I hover over the button, but when the mouse leaves the button, the message I initially set for statusBar disappears. However, I would like to be able to keep the message I set for statusBar.

Here is the minimum reproducible example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        saveAct = QtWidgets.QAction('&Save', self)
        saveAct.setShortcut('F5')
        saveAct.setStatusTip('Saves your file')
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Hello")

        self.menuBar().addAction(saveAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple menu')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#permanent-message):

> Normal and Permanent messages are displayed by creating a small widget (QLabel, QProgressBar or even QToolButton) and then adding it to the status bar using the addWidget() or the addPermanentWidget() function.

The solution is to create a QLabel and add it to the toolbar.

```
class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        saveAct = QtWidgets.QAction('&Save', self)
        saveAct.setShortcut('F5')
        saveAct.setStatusTip('Saves your file')
        self.normalMessage = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello')
        self.statusBar().addWidget(self.normalMessage)

        self.menuBar().addAction(saveAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple menu')
        self.show()
```